# Set Theory Proof Practice Problem Help [CONFUSED]

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'm an undergraduate who has just got exposed to proofs for the first time. Currently, we're working with sets and set theory proofs in particularly. So, I have tried learning all the vital concepts relating to sets, but I still am struggling with proofs as I am not sure how to go about starting them. Here's an example proof question from my math textbook.

[image: Question]

So, I understand that what the question is asking is to basically prove this statement using the given information (A complement is a subset of B) and using this build my proof. What I have tried doing is: claiming that since X∈A∪B = S then X∈A or X∈B but I'm not sure how to continue, and finish this proof.

Could you please put me in the right directions or give me some directions? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There is absent context. For one thing, we don't know what $S$ is; is the set over which we take the complement of $A$?

Comment: remember that $A$ and its complement span the whole set. and $B$ contains the complement of A.

Comment: You want to *prove* that $A\cup B=S$, but you cannot assume this is true without first having proved it.  You start with your hypothesis, $A^c\subseteq B$ and from this you then prove that it *follows* that $A\cup B= S$.

Comment: I'm sorry but it just says that S is the universe of discourse, but doesn't actually mention any of its elements.

Comment: That's all well and good.  Saying that $S$ is the universe of discourse is exactly what we needed clarified.  The exact contents of $S$ beyond that are irrelevant.

Comment: My problem is that I am not exactly sure how to prove this using the given information. Should I assume that A∪B must be a subset of S and go from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I have tried doing is: claiming that since X∈A∪B = S ...

OK, you are immediately doing something wrong here: You need to *show* that A∪B = S, so you should not assume it.

The basic set-up you should use is to show two things:

First assume that $X\in A \cup B$.  Now show that $X\in S$. This shows $A\cup B \subseteq S$

Now assume that $X\in S$, and show that $X\in A \cup B$. This shows $S \subseteq A\cup B$

Of course, in both cases, use the fact that $A^C \subseteq B$

Once you have shown these two things, you have shown that $A\cup B = S$

Comment: I see! So by showing that A∪B and S are subsets of each other, we imply that they are equal using some logical reasonings?

Comment: Also, I am not sure how to actually include the given information in the proof. Are we required to use this information?

Comment: @Abwatts Yes, two sets are equal if they are subsets of each other. Typically no further argument needs to be made for that, since that is such a basic truth in set theory.  And yes, you need to use the given information that $A^C \subseteq B$ ... without it, you won't be able to show that if $X \in S$, then $X \in A \cup B$  (you don;t need it to show that if $X \in A \cup B$ then $X \in S$, since $S$ is the universe of discourse (of which $A$ and $B$ are subsets) so *of course* $X \in S$)